# Load External Jar in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a jar file that contains this class:

```
@Configuration
public class ExternalConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "tab")
  public Tab getTab() {
    return new Tab();
  }
}
```

My Spring boot Application looks like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@ComponentScan("com.xxx")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
    Object o1 = context.getBean("tab");
  }

}
```

I am getting this when running:

```
A component required a bean named 'tab' that could not be found.
```

I have tried every combination of loader.path that I could think of like this:

```
loader.path=/opt/lib
loader.path=/opt/lib/
loader.path=/opt/lib/external.jar
```

I put those in application.properties and tried it in loader.properties. 
I can also confirm that the package for ExternalConfiguration falls under com.xxx   -- so it should be scanned for components correct?

What am I doing wrong?  How do I load an external jar and get Spring to load it like normal.  I do NOT want to add it to my pom.xml.
*EDIT*  When I do add it in my pom, it works as expected.

What I really want is to tell Spring  "load everything in this directory"

Any ideas?

Comment: loader.properties is in the standard /src/main/resources.   I did not comfigure loader.home.  I will give that a try.

Comment: I can confirm that the loader.properties is in the /BOOT-INF/classes directory in the jar file.

Comment: none.  I just did a "find / -name loader.properties"  and the only one was for this project.

Comment: Have a look into the log file. `PropertiesLauncher` is logging the location and the properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can load external jars with following command

```
java -cp your.jar -Dloader.path=/home/user/lib org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

jars that you wan't to add should be compiled as non-executable, without BOOT-INF

and add dependency

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-loader</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```